# I can no longer browse files on an android phone

Tags: nautilus, android, mtp

I have this Huawei P10 lite and I'm having a problem connecting it with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS computer.

This already worked in the past, but something is different today. I connect the phone via USB cable, select Device File manager (MTP) and then I should see the files on my phone. In Nautilus I can only see a Huawei "My CDROM" mount, which contains Autorun.inf, an .exe binary and some other files. No trace of my phone sdcard mount.

I tried to run: sudo apt-get install mtpfs
Doesn't help.

Again, this did work in the past. I did the phone and desktop update in the meantime, so I'm not sure which one screwed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei P10. The same. gMTP did the trick.
- Start gMTP,
- Switch from charging to MTP mode (on the phone),
- "Connect" - button in gMTP.
- Very Long Wait,
- gMtp shows a dialog (internal memory/SD card),
- Select desired one,
- one more Very Long Wait
- Profit.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Damn you Nautilus!